# Why do SKPhysicsContactDelegate on a separate class is not being called

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have been trying to add a contact delegate to my GameScene:

```
self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = ContactManager()
```

However, I am doing this by having the contact delegate (ContactManager class) on a separate class, to avoid having that much code on my GameScene. This is my contact delegate:

```
class ContactManager : NSObject, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

   func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
      print("they touched!")
   }

}
```

The problem is that when object 1 collides with object 2 it does not run the method didBegin(). However, I know the problem is not the bitmasks because I made the GameScene inherit the SKPhysicsContactDelete and set the delegate to self and the method didBegin() worked. So the issue is that the class ContactManager() is not linking up correctly, how can I make sure the a contact manager on a separate class from the GameScene works?

Comment: nothing retains `ContactManager` so as soon as you exit the function, it becomes nil

Comment: you need a global variable in your scene: `private let contactManager = ContactManager()`, then set `self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = contactManager`

Comment: Only one object can be set as a delegate of a physics world. So if you set self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = contactManagerInstance, and later in your code you set it again to self (where self is a scene), only the scene will receive contact notifications. So you can either have a scene listening for the contacts or the ContactManager. So basically do what Knight0fDragon said, make an property and set it to be a contact delegate.

Comment: @Whirlwind good explanation!! I'm going to start copying your comments as answers, then run a bounty or something to transfer the points to you. Stop being lazy and write an answer!! :D

Comment: @Fluidity Lol :) I will try :)

Comment: But why isn't the variable kep as an attribute of self, since it is assigned to its physicsBody?

Comment: @pablo you have to use the `@` symbol to get their attention for that question :)

Comment: @Whirlwind  
But why isn't the variable kep as an attribute of self, since it is assigned to its physicsBody?

Comment: @pablo I am sorry but your question doesnt make sense to me. There was no mention of any physicsBody in my comment.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon could you please post your response as an answer, this solved my problem.

Comment: @Whirlwind he meant physicsWorld

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`contactDelegate` on SKPhysicsWorld is `unowned(unsafe)`, which means that it will not increase the retain counter, and will not be treated as an optional.

This means that you are responsible for retaining whatever object you place into this variable.

In your code `self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = ContactManager()` You are setting the contact delegate to be a local copy of ContactManager.  Since nothing is retaining this, it will immediately be discarded because the retain count is set to 0.

This is the reason why in most cases, people use `self` as the delegate, because you are guaranteed that `self` exists.

To remedy this situation, make sure you have a property that retains your ContactManger so that you do not lose it upon creation.

```
class Example : SKScene
{
  let contactManager = ContactManager()
  func someKindOfSetup()
  { 
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = contactManager
  }
}
```

Source:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skphysicsworld/1449602-contactdelegate

Comment: And in this case, it would be useful to mention that Example should be a subclass of an SKScene. @Knight0fDragon, did you know that we *can* subclass SKPhysicsWorld ? I dont know if there can be some use of that fact... Also, there is no mention in docs that this class shouldnt be sublclassed (like it is said for SKTexture or SKAction classes) Or maybe I haven't noticed that part in docs...

Comment: @Whirlwind they say not to subclass SKView either, but I do that anyway lol

Answer (score 1):

As per Whirlwind:

> Only one object can be set as a delegate of a physics world. So if you set `self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = contactManagerInstance`, and later in your code you set it again to self (where self is a scene), only the scene will receive contact notifications. So you can either have a scene listening for the contacts or the `ContactManager`. So basically do what Knight0fDragon said, make a property and set it to be a contact delegate.

Comment: I don't, I only set the contactDelegate once. I mentioned both scenarios, but they both take place independently. I only set self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate once, whether it is self or the ContactManager class, it is done once. I did both for the sake of testing it out.